# How can I send array from one activity (intent) to another?

Tags: android

```
list.addAll(paireDevice);
Intent i= new Intent(bluetooth.this, ShowPairedDevice.class);
i.getParcelableArrayListExtra("Device.list",(ArrayList<?extends Parcelable>)list);
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***`now it's work with the was in getParcelableArrayListExtra instead ofputParcelableArrayListExtra`***

### list.addAll(paireDevice); Intent i= new Intent(bluetooth.this, ShowPairedDevice.class); i.putParcelableArrayListExtra("Device.list", (ArrayList) list); startActivity(i);

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("Device1");
    list.add("Device2");
    list.add("Device3");


    Intent i = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("Device.list", list);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

}

```
public class NewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private String TAG = NewActivity.class.getSimpleName();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new);

    ArrayList<String> list = (ArrayList<String>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("Device.list");

    for (String device: list){
        Log.i(TAG, "Devices: " + device);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Really? Try this code copy and past. What going wrong?